# Алгоритм размещения элементов в css сетке

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Допустим есть сетка, в которой явным образом не указан алгоритм размещения блоков и при скроле подгружаются новые блоки. Как задать им алгоритм размещения? Пример сетки: [image: Пример сетки]

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: purple;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(6n + 1) {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(6n + 2), .grid-item:nth-child(6n + 3) {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">12</div>
</div>
```